# Python Bindings for Apache ZooKeeper

Tags: apache-zookeeper, python-bindings

Can someone tell me where can I find the "latest" Python bindings for Apache ZooKeeper ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are at the [ZooKeeper SVN repository](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ZooKeeper/HowToContribute).